# Conditional interface

Tags: c#

For a project I'm on I'm unfortunately stuck with `.NET 2.0` (many of our target machines are still Windows XP), which means no `Optional` type as [Nuget's `Optional` library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Optional/)  requires `.NET 3.5`.

Fortunately, rolling your own `Optional` type is pretty easy, but I've encountered one issue.

I would like something like the following:

```
class Optional<T> : (IComparable<Optional<T>> when T : IComparable<T>)
```

That is, I want my `Optional` type to implement `Comparable`, but only when the underlying type is `Comparable`.

The above syntax is sadly not valid, but is there a way achieve what I'm looking for?

Indeed this problem isn't confined to `Optional`, it will apply to any container type one wants to define that can implement it's internal type's interfaces.

I do realise I could do this:

```
class Optional<T>
class ComparableOptional<T> : Optional<T>, Comparable<ComparableOptional<T>> 
  where T : Comparable<T>
```

But this seems a bit silly, as then we really have to go down this rabbit hole:

```
class Optional<T>

class EquatableOptional<T> : 
    Optional<T>, 
    IEquatable<EquatableOptional<T>>
  where T : IEquatable<T>

class ComparableOptional<T> : 
    EquatableOptional<T>,
    IComparable<ComparableOptional<T>>, 
    IEquatable<ComparableOptional<T>>
  where T : IComparable<T>
```

Furthermore, if `T` is `Enumerable`, `Optional<T>` can also be `Enumerable` (returning an empty enumerator if there is no value) so then we've got even more classes.

As `Enumerable` is orthogonal to `Equatable` and `Comparable`, we'd really need the following classes:

```
class Optional
class EquatableOptional
class ComparableOptional
class EnumerableOptional
class EnumerableEquatableOptional
class EnumerableComparableOptional
```

to cover all cases. Add another orthogonal interface and you've got 12 classes.

Is there a less messy approach that allows me to define interfaces conditionally? This seems like a common issue with any collection.

Comment: .NET 3.5 could be installed on XP, so I'm not sure what the issue would be with requiring it? (Absent the fact that the whole XP situation is unsupported anyway) (And given that 3.0 and 3.5 were in-place updates to what remains the 2.0 CLR anyway)

Comment: What stops you from doing? `public class Optional<T> { }
    public class ComparableOptional<T> : Optional<Comparable<T>> { }` I know its not best solution but still?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: the entire product must stay compatible with .NET 2.0 because a variety of business and support reasons, partly as we don't have much control over our client's machines. However this question isn't about business strategy anyway, and my question would apply to many container types in any case.

Comment: @kuskmen: the number of types grows exponentially with new interfaces as detailed in the question. It seems like a very messy solution that would be hard to maintain.

Comment: And how is it related to Optional from that nuget package? I mean I guess it has the same limitations?

Comment: @Evk: perhaps it does I'm not sure. I was just giving background information on what I was trying to achieve.

Comment: @Clinton Have you considered forking the required libraries (e.g. https://github.com/nlkl/Optional) to make them .Net 2.0 compatible?

Comment: I see, but it's a bit confusing because now people might think your problem is in running on .NET 2.0, while in reality .NET version doesn't matter for your question.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer yes or alternatively just submit a PR but I still need to resolve this question for my use case

Comment: @Clinton: Have you considered explicit methods on your type, `AsComparable()`, `AsEquatable()` etc that would safely check the type and return something upon the check? That makes the client call these in an explicit way, though.

Comment: @Evk: the question is titled "Conditional interface" and asks at the end quite explicitly about how to define conditional interfaces so I'm not sure it's that confusing. If someone provides a later `.NET` approach to this problem that would be a start.

Comment: @Clinton Do you have a more specific example for the generic types? As it is now I would say remove the constraints, make `Optional` always `IEquatable` and `IComparable` and throw a `NotSupportedException` if the generic type doesn't inherit from them. **edit** I just realized that would make it a rather bloated superclass if you also have all the other interfaces so that might not be a good idea after all.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer: that's a bit scary but perhaps the best option. It's currently being used with a number of types.

Comment: Are you concerned about performance?

Comment: Only other option I see would be an equally ridiculous amount of implicit or explicit conversion operators or a linq-like `Cast<>` method (or what Wiktor suggested).

Comment: @kuskmen: not incredibly so at this point. More concerned about type safety, i.e. I'd like the compiler to catch improper usage of `Optional<T>` just like it catches improper usage of `T` when the interface is not available.

Comment: Anyway it's not possible, so just copy implementation from https://github.com/nlkl/Optional/blob/master/src/Optional/Option_Maybe.cs - it's a reasonable one, and uses `Comparer<T>.Default` and `EqualityComparer<T>.Default`. That's best you can do.

Comment: Hmm I think you can do something with dynamic proxies implementing interface runtime, but then all that type safety is lost, I am out of ideas :(

Comment: I mean its *basically* `Nullable` for classes so .... Implementing *all* supported interfaces and always returning a sensible fallback might not be the worst idea. The type-safety is of course a concern .... yeah I'm out of ideas too.

Comment: After reading all comments, and Flater's answer, I am wondering *why* you would need your Optional type to implement all these interfaces in the first place. In a language like F# you would be required to either unpack the option, in which case you don't need any comparison interfaces, or use higher-order functions (Option.map, Option.bind, etc.) to do the unpacking for you behind the scenes, in which case you don't need any comparison interfaces either. Should your goal not be to model this kind of behaviour?

Comment: @dumetrulo: comparing data structures for equality is a pretty common operation, particularly in test cases. If these data structures contain `Optional`  I need equality on `Optional`, and if I want compare collections of them ignoring order I also need comparisons so I can sort them. The actual sort order in this case doesn't matter but it needs to exist and be consistent.

Comment: @Clinton: I see… in that case, I'd say you need the members of your data structure to implement the relevant interfaces anyway, and should probably go with having your Optional type implement all required interfaces, and throw exceptions (or return default values) in case the contained value does not implement a required interface.

Answer (score 3):

What you want to do infringes on the intention of how generics work in C#.

You're essentially arguing that **type safety** should be used as **type possibility**. Which is against the current C# ideology where you know a type's definition (and which methods and properties it exposes) for a fact.

The correct approach would be to have a second `ComparableOptional<T>` which derives from `Optional<T>` but adds an additional constraint:

```
class ComparableOptional<T> : Optional<T> where T : Comparable<T>
```

There is no benefit to your suggestion, other than the lazy approach of wanting to mash two different classes together. Even if the language would allow you to do so, I see no discernible benefit to this approach (compared to `ComparableOptional<T>`) but it does introduce a whole range of runtime errors that you can now encounter.

---

```
class Optional<T> : (IComparable<Optional<T>> when T : IComparable<T>) {}
```

Suppose everything works the way you expect it to.

```
var optionalPerson = new Optional<Person>() { Person = myPerson };
var optionalPerson2 = new Optional<Person>() { Person = myPerson2 };

int result = optionalPerson.CompareTo(optionalPerson2);
```

Should this work? In C# currently, it doesn't. But according to you, it should be able to if `Person : IComparable<Person>`. Your argument should be something like this:

> *Since the compiler sees me use the type `Person : IComparable<Person>`, it should be able to deduce that `Optional<T>` must now implement `IComparable<T>` and therefore the `CompareTo()` should be available.*

The solidity of your argument rests solely on the fact that you **know for a fact** (at compile time) that the type you're using implements the needed interface.

But what about this code:

```
public void DoSomething<T>(Optional<T> opt1, Optional<T> opt2)
{
    int result = opt1.CompareTo(opt2);
}
```

Should this work? You can't know, since you don't know which type will be used! Compounding the issue even further:

```
public void DoSomething(string optionalType, object opt1, object opt2)
{
    var castObj = Convert.ChangeType(opt1, Type.GetType(optionalType)));
    var castObj2 = Convert.ChangeType(opt2, Type.GetType(optionalType)));

    int result = castObj .CompareTo(castObj2);
}
```

This method passes the used type as a string. So now you would expect the compiler to *check the value of the string* to figure out whether or not the generic type constraint of the type that is represented in the string implements a particular interface.

WHat if that string is retrieved from a database or external web service? Is the compiler now required to have an active database/web connection before it can decide whether your code is valid?

This is running out of hand.

*Your likely counterarguments:*

> *As long as I only use this method with types that implement `IComparable<T>`, the compiler should not throw an error. When I use a type that does not implement `IComparable<T>`, it should throw an error on the `int result` line.*

That is not intuitive, and is going to lead to developer confusion.

> *The compiler should always assume that conditional generic type constraints are true*.

So how would you handle mutually exclusive conditional generic type constraints, which logically will never both be true?

Welcome to the world of debugging hell. This is bad practice for the same reason that you shouldn't use `dynamic` over strongly typed approaches: it makes code considerably harder to maintain and develop.

Such an approach requires much more runtime testing to ensure that you haven't made a mistake somewhere that will blow up in your face. And runtime testing is a flawed approach.

Comment: Simply add `where T : IComparable<T>` to the end of `DoSomething`. Indeed that's already quite legal `C#`.

Comment: @Clinton: But there's simply no point to it. If you're already expecting the developer to specify the generic type constraint, you could just as easily have expected the developer to use `ComparableOptional<T>` instead of `Optional<T>`. There is no benefit to your suggestion, other than the lazy approach of wanting to mash two different classes together.

Comment: It avoids the exponential blowup in classes detailed in the question alone with the associated maintenance nightmare of maintaining all the methods for a dozen or so classes.

Comment: @Clinton: There is no blowup. Everything that _doesn't_ rely on `IComparable<T>` gets put in `Optional<T>`. Everything that _does_ rely on `IComparable<T>` gets put in `ComparableOptional<T>`. Inheritance between `ComparableOptional<T>` and `Optional<T>` prevents code duplication.  You end up with **the exact same amount of code**, but it's distributed across two classes, each of which has a single verifiable responsibility.

Comment: what happens when I add in `IEquatable` and `IEnumerable` into this mix as I suggested in the answer?

Comment: @Clinton: `Optional<T>` shouldn't even care about the interfaces implemented by `T`. Your generic wrapper class should be as agnostic as possible. There is no point in providing custom code for custom cases in a generic class. `List<T>` doesn't care one bit about what its `T` is. Neither does `Lazy<T>`, `Nullable<T>`, ... Your approach is wrong to begin with.

Comment: `public void DoSomething<T>(T opt1, T opt2) where T : Comparable<T>` is quite reasonable and valid C#. `public void DoSomething<T>(Optional<T> opt1, Optional<T> opt2) where T : Comparable<T>` is pretty much the same thing. Just need to know how to write `Optional<T>` then.

Comment: @Clinton: Your different way of doing things provides no benefit compared to methods that actually work; and it introduces a range of issues; from hard to maintain code to hidden logic to runtime exceptions.

Comment: The question is about compile time checking, not runtime. The interfaces `T` supports can vary based on `T` at compile time. I'm just asking how to make the interfaces `X<T>` vary based on `T` at compile time. All compile time stuff here, your runtime exceptions thing is a red hearing and not the intent of my question.

Comment: @Clinton: `I'm just asking how to make the interfaces X<T> vary based on T at compile time`. You can't. That's the point. It's not possible. Type safety inherently means that the type (and therefore the available properties/methods) **cannot vary** (type _safety_ is based on type _guarantees_ which means an _absence of _-variation_). This is how it is intended to work. None of your arguments change anything about the fact that C# works the way it is designed to work. Type safety is an intentional feature. Learn to work with it instead of argue against it.

Comment: But it can. `Int` and `String` are different types so can have different interfaces, similarly `X<Int>` and `X<String>` are different types so why can't they have different interfaces?

Comment: @Clinton `The interfaces a type T supports depends on the value of T` No it doesn't. Unless a specific generic type constraint is defined, `T` is not assumed to implement _any_ interface whatsoever, since `T` is then expected to work for **every possible type**. Since not every type implements every interface, that means that `T` becomes the _lowest common denominator_ (i.e. any type, with no expectations about the interfaces it implements).

Comment: All `Int`s should have the same interfaces, all `String`s should have the same interfaces, all `X<Int>`s should have the same interfaces, and all `X<String>`s should have the same interfaces, but why does `X<String>` have to have the same interfaces as `X<Int>` when `String` can have different interfaces to `Int`? Allowing the former to have different interfaces to each is no more type unsafe than allowing the latter, which is allowed.

Comment: @Clinton: Please don't edit a comment and completely change the content. In response to your new comment; you are misunderstanding how generics work **inside** the generic class itself. **Externally**, code that uses a `List<string>` will see the list members as being of type `string`. But **internal to the `List<T>` class definition itself**, the code does not know what type `T` is representing and if it's currently a string or not (that is the definition of being generic, after all).

Comment: The compiler in any case sees these as separate types. I'm talking compile time, not runtime here. `Int` and `String` are just as different `X<Int>` and `X<String>` at compile time. I'm just trying to apply the same things we do with the former to the latter, again, at compile time, not runtime.

Comment: @Clinton: This is a pointless discussion. You are trying to apply the _external_ knowledge of the consumer of a generic class (which knows which particular type it currently wishes to use) to the _internal_ logic of the generic class itself (which only knows what possible types can be used, and does not know which type is _currently_ being used). This means you don't quite understand the internal working of generic types; and you should brush up on the documentation.